# Widget view not updating when state changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to fetch a URL asynchronously and then render it in my widget. For some reason though the widget view never refreshes once the URL becomes available.

```swift
@MainActor
class MapUrlModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var url: String? {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
            print("changed")
        }
    }

    init() {}

    func load(
        ampm: String,
        date: String,
        publicationTime: String,
        region: String
    ) async throws {
        self.url = await getMapImage(
            ampm: ampm,
            date: date,
            publicationTime: publicationTime,
            region: region
        )
    }
}

struct MapWidgetView: View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    // I also tried with @StateObject
    @ObservedObject private var mapUrlModel = MapUrlModel()

    let entry: MapWidgetTimelineEntry
    let locationDetail: LocationDetail?
    let bulletins: [ContextualBulletin]
    let bestMatchingBulletin: ContextualBulletin?
    let background: String
    let reportDate: String?
    var reportMapUrl: String?
    
    init(entry: MapWidgetTimelineEntry) {
        self.entry = entry
        self.locationDetail = entry.locationDetail
        self.bulletins = entry.bulletins
        self.bestMatchingBulletin = entry.bulletins.first(where: {
            $0.locationMatching
        })
        self.background = entry.background.id
        self.reportDate = entry.reportDate
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Map")
            if self.mapUrlModel.url != nil {
                Text("Here")
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: self.mapUrlModel.url!))
            } else {
                Text(self.mapUrlModel.url ?? "fallback")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            if (self.bestMatchingBulletin != nil && self.reportDate != nil) {
                let publicationTime = self.bestMatchingBulletin!.data.metaDataProperty.MetaData.dateTimeReport
                let region = self.bestMatchingBulletin!.data.gml_id
                
                Task { [self] in
                    do {
                        try await mapUrlModel.load(
                            ampm: "am",
                            date: String(entry.reportDate!.split(separator: "T").first!),
                            publicationTime: publicationTime,
                            region: region
                        )
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onChange(of: mapUrlModel.url) {
            print("Henlo")
        }.environmentObject(mapUrlModel)
        .containerBackground(for: .widget) {}
    }
}
```

I have verified that `willSet` is called and the URL is generated correctly, but I can't understand why it's not rerendering the view?

Comment: All of the fetching must be handled in a `TimelineProvider`. The view must only display the data. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit

Comment: There's some odd stuff going on here. You shouldn't be calling `objectWillChange` in `willSet`. `@Published` does that automatically. Second, you should be using `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject` where you own `MapUrlModel`. There's no reason to use `environmentObject` when there aren't any child views that access `MapUrlModel`

Comment: Widgets are like a gif, each entry being an image. they don't listen or change make all your properties `let` you can only "reload" to pass more data. There is some animation that can be done but the "work" that a widget can do is minimal.

Comment: In SwiftUI async/await is `.task` not `Task {}` and you can just remove the legacy Combine `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Thanks @Timmy! Doing the work in the timeline provider did the trick, thanks again.